# Como hacer un loop dentro de una plantilla emacscript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hola tengo esta duda es posible hacer un loop a un array e imprimir los valores dentro de una plantilla ecmascript-6 ? como este ejemplo que deseo realizar:

```
const myString = `
   name: ${name}
   cell: ${cellphone}
   ${devices.forEach((device)=>`imei: ${device}`)}
`
```

result:

```
name: John
cell: 79874982749
undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, es posible. El problema que tienes es que estás utilizando la funcion `forEach`. Estás evaluando dentro del string lo que devuelve dicha función, y dicha función no devuelve nada (`undefined`) ya que se utiliza para producir efectos fuera de la función, como por ejemplo, modificar un array externo.

Para que inserte el resultado dentro del string debes sustituir esta función por el `map` que sí devuelve un array con el resultado aplicado a cada elemento del array original:

```
const myString = `
   name: ${name}
   cell: ${cellphone}
   ${devices.map((device)=>`imei: ${device}`)}
`
```

Comment: Esa es la solución, porque ya la probé. Gracias por tu aporte sergiomse